# Unable to get output from Tensorflow lite object detection model in C

Tags: c, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I trained an Tensorflow Lite object detection model with Yolo architecture in Python. Now I am trying to do the inference in C but I cannot make it work after the interpreter is invoked.

The `main.c` file looks something like this:

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_experimental.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/common.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/c/builtin_op_data.h"

int inputImageHeight = 416;
int inputImageWidth = 416;
int channel = 3;
int imageSize = inputImageHeight * inputImageWidth * channel;
float imageDataBuffer[imageSize]; // some steps lead to store an image to this buffer. The image is set to the model's input size (416x416) and normalized to [0, 1].

// Load model.
TfLiteModel* model = TfLiteModelCreateFromFile(modelFilePath);

// Create the interpreter.
TfLiteInterpreter* interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, NULL);

// Allocate tensors.
if(TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter) != kTfLiteOk)
    {
      disposeTfLiteObjects(model, interpreter);
      return -1;
    }

int inputDims[4] = {1, inputImageHeight, inputImageWidth, channel};
if(TfLiteInterpreterResizeInputTensor(interpreter, 0, inputDims, 4)!= kTfLiteOk)
    {
      disposeTfLiteObjects(model, interpreter);
      return -1;
    }

if(TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter) != kTfLiteOk)
    {
      disposeTfLiteObjects(model, interpreter);
      return -1;
    }
```

```
// Invoke the TensorFlow intepreter given the input and the model.

// The input tensor.
TfLiteTensor* inputTensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, 0);

// Copy image data into input tensor.
if(TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(inputTensor, imageDataBuffer, imageSize * sizeof(float)) != kTfLiteOk)
    {
      disposeTfLiteObjects(model, interpreter);
      return -1;
    }

// Invoke interpreter.
if(TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(interpreter) != kTfLiteOk)
    {
      disposeTfLiteObjects(model, interpreter);
      return -1;
    }
```

Until this point everything seems to work fine. From here, I am failing to extract the output data.

From Python I know that the output is a couple of tensors with dimension `[1,13,13,18]` and `[1,26,26,18]`. They represent a detection following the YOLO format: [x, y, W, H, detection_prob, class_prob] (only 1 class to be detected) with 3 anchors (6*3=18) over a 13x13 grid. Two tensors due to two anchor ratios.

In Python, fetching the output data results in a series of vectors to be prost-processed to get the positive detections and later non-max suppression.

In C, however, I am not sure how to manage this step. So far I assigned the output tensor like:

```
// Extract the output tensor data.
const TfLiteTensor* outputTensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 0);
```

but I don't know how to properly extract the data.

Via `gdb` I could see that, at least, the first 4 dimensions coincide with [1,13,13,18]:

```
(gdb) print outputTensor->dims[0]
$10 = {size = 4, data = 0x555555785e04}
(gdb) print outputTensor->dims[1]
$11 = {size = 1, data = 0x555555785e08}
(gdb) print outputTensor->dims[2]
$12 = {size = 13, data = 0x555555785e0c}
(gdb) print outputTensor->dims[3]
$13 = {size = 13, data = 0x555555785e10}
(gdb) print outputTensor->dims[4]
$14 = {size = 18, data = 0x555555785e14}
```

I couldn't find the equivalent to [1,26,26,18] in the remaining dimensions though.

If I print the output tensor data:

```
(gdb) print outputTensor->data
$3 = {i32 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, i64 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, f = 0x7ffff561c8c0, f16 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, 
  f64 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, raw = 0x7ffff561c8c0 "", raw_const = 0x7ffff561c8c0 "", 
  uint8 = 0x7ffff561c8c0 "", b = 0x7ffff561c8c0, i16 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, c64 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, 
  c128 = 0x7ffff561c8c0, int8 = 0x7ffff561c8c0 "", data = 0x7ffff561c8c0}
```

First position of `.f` field:

```
(gdb) print outputTensor->data.f[0]
$5 = -nan(0x400000)
```

Anyone knows how to get the output detections? The goal is to get the "raw" detections and post-process them afterwards. Although a "one-shoot" approach could work too.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said you have 2 outputs and the first one is correct with shape [1, 13, 13, 18].
So you need to fetch the second one

```
const TfLiteTensor* output_tensor_2 =
      TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, 1);
/// Copy the data like below to your own buffer, you can adjust to whatever type you want.

TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(output_tensor_2, output.data(),
                          output.size() * sizeof(float));
```